# DRY Up Rails HTTP Basic Auth

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, active-record

Can anyone think of a way to DRY up this code or is there a way to make it more efficient or quicker. Its what authenticates a user with my API and i want to make it as fast as possible.

```
def authenticate!
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |access_key, secret_key|
    @current_app = App.find_by_access_key(access_key)
    @current_app.secret_key == secret_key ? true : false
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not much to say, just two notes:

- Common mistake of redundant boolean check: `some_boolean ? true : false` -> `some_boolean`.
- You can either use the bang find method or check the returned value, but not just use without a check.

So simply:

```
def authenticate!
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |access_key, secret_key|
    @current_app = App.find_by_access_key(access_key)
    @current_app && @current_app.secret_key == secret_key
  end
end
```